# selecting all rows where a column has an specific ID

Tags: mysql, sql, find-in-set

So I have a badly designed database (I think) which I can't change. It's a twitter like app where the users can follow each other. Every user has it`s row in the table, and in that table there is a column named 'following' which represents all USERID's that a user is following. In that column there is a list of USERID's separated with a coma. So lets say the user with the ID 1 is following users 2 and 3 and the user with ID 2 is following user 1 the table would look like this, user 3 is not following anybody.

```
USERID  |  username         |  following  
-------------------------------------------
1       |  some user        |  2,3                
2       |  test1            |  1                
3       |  test2            |
```

Question is how do I show all the users which user 1 is following?

EDIT 1

The code that did not work from 491243, posting here, maybe I missed something in php

```
$USERID = $_GET['userid'];//this has a value, so not the problem here
$sql_select = "SELECT B.USERID FROM users A INNER JOIN users B ON FIND_IN_SET(B.USERID, B.following) > 0 WHERE B.USERID = '$USERID'";
$result_select = mysqli_query($link,$sql_select);
while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($result_select))
{
    $following = $record['USERID'];
    var_dump($following); //result is nothing, not even NULL
}
```

EDIT 2
Just for sanity check I did this:

```
 $sql_select = "SELECT USERID FROM users WHERE USERID = '1'";
 $result_select = mysqli_query($link,$sql_select);
 while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($result_select))
 {
    $following = $record['USERID'];
    var_dump($following); //result is 1, like it`s supposed to be
 }
```

Is it possible my PHP code is wrong for the query in the replays?

Comment: Why is it that people responsible for such a bad design never have to actually use it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for [FIND_IN_SET()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php)

```
SELECT  userid, username
FROM    tableName
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('1', following);
```

**[SAMPLE FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9efda/3)**

Comment: This is crazy, I see it`s working in fiddle and it does not work for me in localhost...

Comment: can you post the original data which is not getting in your machine

Comment: Is it possible the problem is the MySQL version. My wamp has 5.5.24 and the fiddle uses 5.5.32?

Comment: Awesome it`s working now, I am marking your answer as correct. Although I am not sure why it`s not working the previous way in my localhost when it did work in fiddle. Anyway tnx. And thanks for the all the other answers.

Answer (score 5):

Your table schema is in bad shape. you should normalize it properly. But to answer you question, you can still get the result you want using `JOIN` and `FIND_IN_SET`

```
SELECT  b.userid, b.username
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN tableName b
            ON FIND_IN_SET(b.userID, a.following) > 0
WHERE   a.userID = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82be1/2)

My preferred design would be

**User Table**

- **UserID (PK)**
- UserName

**Following Table**

- **UserID (FK)**   - also a PK with FollowID
- **FollowID (FK)**

Comment: Ty you for the db structure suggestion I wanted to ask that (how to do this better). But for now I need this. Your answer does not work, I do var_dump and get nothing from the query.

Comment: but it works on the fiddle right? maybe you have not correctly implemented it.